# Como personalizo un formulario de una tabla intermedia en Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo una **tabla intermedia** que hace uso de los usuarios de Django para realizar los registros. La **idea** es hacer uso de las clases basadas en vistas. Suelo confundir mucho a la gente asi que enumero los resultados "una imagen vale mas que mil palabras no".

El **modelo** de la competencia es

```py
class Competences(models.Model):
    idcompetence = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fkarea = models.ForeignKey(Areas, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='fkarea')
    codecompetence = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    namecompetencees = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    descriptioncompetencees = models.CharField(max_length=350)
```

Este el **modelo** de la tabla intermedia

```py
class Competenciasusuario(models.Model):
    idregistrocompusuario = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fkcompetence = models.ForeignKey(Competences, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='fkcompetence')
    fkuser = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='fkuser')
    tiene = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
```

La **vista** por defecto basada en clases usando todos los campos

```py
class registroCompetencias(CreateView):
    model = Competenciasusuario
    fields = '__all__'
    form_class = RegistroCompForm
    template_name = 'competenciasusuario_form.html'
    success_url = 'home'
```

La que estoy creando para el formulario que quiero

```py
class registroCompetencias(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Competenciasusuario
    fields = ['fkcompetence', 'tiene']
    form_class = RegistroCompForm
    template_name = 'competenciasusuario_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    
    def form_valid(self,form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        form.instance.fkuser = self.request.user.id
        print('ID user login\t', self.request.user.id)
```

Por cierto como aun no se si funciona se puede redireccionar de esta forma **usando** el name de la url que se crea para la vista.

```py
path('', views.index, name='home'),
# la del registro que menciono
path('registroCompetencias', registroCompetencias.as_view(), name='nuevasComp'),
```

Continuando cuando quiero pedir solo algunos campos `fields = ['fkcompetence', 'tiene']` me lanza este error, **supongo** que es por la llave foránea de pronto el formulario esta mal.

```py
class RegistroCompForm(forms.Form):
        class Meta:
                model = Competenciasusuario
                fields = [
                        'fkcompetence',
                        'tiene'
                ]
                labels = {
                        'fkcompetence':'Competencia',
                        'tiene': '¿Crees tener la competencia?'
                }
                widgets = {
                        'fkcompetence': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','required': True, 'placeholder': 'Seleccione la competencia'}, select = Competences.objects.values_list('idcompetence', 'fkarea__idarea', 'fkarea__nameareaes', 'namecompetencees', 'descriptioncompetencees')),
                        'tiene': forms.BooleanField(required = False)
                }
```

Menciona una consulta sin ella me arroja este error

```
"Specifying both 'fields' and 'form_class' is not permitted."
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying both 'fields' and 'form_class' is not permitted.
```

Agregando dicha consulta

```py
'fkcompetence': forms.TextInput(
                                attrs={'class': 'form-control','required': True, 'placeholder': 'Seleccione la competencia'}, 
                                select = Competences.objects.values_list('idcompetence', 'fkarea_idarea', 'fkarea_nameareaes', 'namecompetencees', 'descriptioncompetencees')
                                ),
```

Me arroja este **error**, no se como implementar la.

```py
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'fkarea_idarea' into field. Choices are: codecompetence, competenciasusuario, descriptioncompetenceen, descriptioncompetencees, examples, fkarea, fkarea_id, idcompetence, linecompetences, namecompetenceen, namecompetencees
```

Aun estoy trabajando en el formulario para el registro, tengo problemas para obtener la llave foranea (de la forma que quiero, idComp, Desc, Area...)

```py
class RegistroCompForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
                model = Competenciasusuario
                fields = [
                        'fkcompetence',
                        'tiene'
                ]
                labels = {
                        'fkcompetence':'Competencia digital',
                        'tiene': '¿Crees tener la competencia?'
                }
                widgets = {
                        'fkcompetence' : forms.ModelChoiceField(
                                queryset=Competenciasusuario.objects.values('fkcompetence__fkarea', 'fkcompetence__fkarea__nameareaes', 'fkcompetence__idcompetence', 'fkcompetence__namecompetencees', 'fkcompetence__descriptioncompetencees', 'tiene'), 
                                empty_label="(Lista)"),
                        'tiene': forms.BooleanField()
                }
```

#### 1. Este es el resultado por *defecto*

Usando todos los campos y sin crear el formulario claro

[image: resultado por defecto]

Naturalmente los **usuarios** no deben salir.

#### 2. El resultado que *deseo*

Las pestañas se debe a que pertenecen a diferentes areas (es un intento por una presentacion mejor y registro multiple naturalmente), y no de uno en uno como en el anterior (el por defecto).

[image: resultado deseado]

#### 3. El resultado con el que me *conformo*

jajaaj supongo que la anterior es pedir demasiado, al menos para mi lo es **pero** es la mas eficiente eso esta claro, a este solo seria quitar los usuarios y tomar el ID del usuario logeado. Aqui **la idea** es mas simple **selecciona** una competencia **muestra** su detalle y listo (y el area seria aun mejor, ahi solo hay nombre_Area).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**A claro**, el fkUser seria de tomar el **ID** del usuario logeado

```html
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fkuser" name="fkuser" value="{{user.id}}"/>
{% endif %}
```

No pongo un **else** porque ya lo controlo la visualización esta pagina con la misma condición (aqui quiero **exponer** otra duda **como controlar** la visualización para **usuario** y **administrador** recalco uso los usuarios de Django, el campo **is_staff** es el que determina el tipo de usuario pero no se como poner lo en la vista hay algunas decoraciones pero no se como usar. DE FORMA simple algunas paginas son para el administrador pero con la condicion del if no existe tal restricción).

Comment: No entiendo el resultado deseado. Por otra parte una ves se seleccione una competencia quieres que aparezca la descripción de dicha competencia? y a su ves quieres que el user loggeado sea el `Fkuser`? es decir que no haya necesidad de mostrar el campo `Fkuser`, pues su valor por defecto es el user loggeado.

Comment: el resultado deseado es un registro de multiple tipo `INSERT INTO(fkcomp, fkuser, tiene) values(1, 1, True),(2, 1, True), (3, 1, False),....`ya que el formulario por defecto solo permite registrar uno a la vez. Y si no es posible? que seleccione y aparezca la descripción de la que selecciono... tomo el id del usuario en la vista

Answer (score 1):

Al parece el problema es que la representación de los objetos en el `<select>` no te gusta. Para que en tu `<select>` no aparezcan los objetos así por ejemplo:

```
<Competences: ...>
```

Debes sobrescribir el método `__str__` del modelo `Competences`, para así representar el objeto de forma "legible":

```
class Competences(models.Model):
    idcompetence = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fkarea = models.ForeignKey(Areas, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='fkarea')
    codecompetence = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    namecompetencees = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    descriptioncompetencees = models.CharField(max_length=350)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fkcompetence.namecompetencees
```

De esta manera, en tu `<select>` los objetos serán representados de manera legible y en ves de mostrarse así: `<Competences: ...>` se mostraran dependiendo el valor del campo `namecompetencees``.

Espero haberte ayudado.